# Show the month name in input box html

Tags: javascript

I want to show the current month name in input box and in feature i put in my sql data as month

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const mnames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const dat = new Date();
var month=( mnames[dat.getMonth()]);
document.getElementById('final').value = month ;
</script>
<input type="text" Id="final" name="final">
```

but now, no result is out put in box please correction my script

Comment: put the `script` after the `input` so the `input` exists when the `script` runs - debugging 101: check the developer tools console for errors - also, use `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {month:'long'})` instead of an Array of month names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the script after `input` element

```html
<input type="text" Id="final" name="final">

<script type="text/javascript">
    const mnames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const dat = new Date();
var month=( mnames[dat.getMonth()]);
document.getElementById('final').value = month ;
</script>
```

**Alternate Solution**

Using [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
const date = new Date();
document.getElementById('final').value = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  month: 'long'
});
```

```html
<input type="text" Id="final" name="final">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve the output by this code also and I recommend that you should load your script after you DOM is loaded , its good practice

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const mnames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const dat = new Date();
var month=( mnames[dat.getMonth()]);
document.getElementById('final').value = month ;
});
</script>
<input type="text" Id="final" name="final">
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your script below your HTML. Currently, your script run before your HTML input load.

```
<input type="text" Id="final" name="final">

<script type="text/javascript">
    const mnames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const dat = new Date();
var month=( mnames[dat.getMonth()]);
document.getElementById('final').value = month ;
</script>
```